# Get a custom Gradle plugin's version from its own code

Tags: plugins, gradle

I wrote a Gradle plugin, its version is specified in its build script.

It is possible for this plugin to be aware of its own version when someone is using it? (i.e. when its `apply(Project project)` method is called)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For my plugins, I embed a field into the MANIFEST.MF file called Implementation-Version during build. Then I read that field in during runtime, by accessing the package like this:

```
def pkg = MyPlugin.class.getPackage()
return pkg.implementationVersion
```

Or using a helper class like: https://github.com/nebula-plugins/nebula-core/blob/master/src/main/groovy/nebula/core/ClassHelper.groovy#L16 to grab arbitrary field from the manifest.

Comment: It works fine, thank you. Snippet to add the property in the manifest: `jar {
  manifest {
    attributes("Implementation-Version": version)
  }
}`

Comment: Very cool approach! It appears that this no longer works on JDK9+, however, presumably since the way the classpath is handled has changed?

Comment: I believe they moved it from package to within the module https://github.com/junit-team/junit5/issues/600

Answer (score 0):

You can also find the version by doing this:

```
    def selfVersion = project.buildscript.configurations.classpath.resolvedConfiguration.resolvedArtifacts.collect {
      it.moduleVersion.id }.findAll { it.name == '<name of plugin>' }.first().version
```